# How to display different model classes into the same recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a few different model data classes that I need to display in a recycler view. All of these item views will look the same, the only difference is that when they are pressed, they need to send over the specific model class to view its detail.

I was thinking of using some interface or parent class, but I'm not sure if they work well with data classes in Kotlin.

I need the supertype to be something like a data class, so in my DiffCallback I can call `oldItem == newItem` for `areContentsTheSame`.

How would you go about trying to extract the common properties each model data class has, using that supertype in the adapter, and then dealing with `areContentsTheSame` for the DiffCallback?

Comment: I think you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252429/4298796

Comment: Not sure if I need to get different view types, since they all should be using the same view layout.